# Angular2 Forms disable control in component with a data-bound value

Tags: angular2-forms

I am disabling controls when the user is not in edit mode.

```
this.theForm = this.builder.group({
   name: [{ value: this.model.name, disabled: !this.isEditMode}, Validators.required],
})
```

When they change to edit mode I want the control to be enabled.  However, it seems that once this is set it will not change then the component value changes.

This was working when I had this in the markup:

```
<input [disabled]="!isEditMode" type="text" formControlName="name"  />
```

This was causing a runtime warning suggesting that I handle it with the formControl.

This is the warning:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true when you set up this control in
>   your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in
>   the DOM for you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed
>   after checked' errors.

Is there a way to bind this value when I setup the control?
Do I need to loop though the controls and toggle this whenever it changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the control change and update it there, something like this (off the top of my head):

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (let nut of this.userSettings.nutrientData) {
      this.foodSettingsForm.controls[nut.abbr].valueChanges
          .subscribe(v => { 
              this.completeValueChange(nut.abbr, v, (mode=="edit" ? false : true));
      });
   }
}

completeValueChange(field: string, value: boolean, disable: boolean) {
   this.myForm.controls[myField]
      .setValue(({value: vale, disabled: disable}, { onlySelf: true });
}
```